# How can I override the default header links in Magento 2 without creating a new navbar?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have started creating my magento project. I have a problem with overriding the default header in luma theme. I created my own theme by extending it from luma theme, it is working but now I have to override the header that contains these links

"Default welcome msg! Sign In  Create an Account ",

I don't want to create a new navbar, how do I override this links and it's href attribute.

In my Part/Store theme, I tried to make a new templates folder in `Part/Store/Magento_Theme/templates/` to override `header.php` file but there is no effect.